# How to disable DMA when using UART on the Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: uart

I have a latency issue when using UART on Raspberry Pi 2 and I want to disable DMA when using UART driver. I know that the Raspberry Pi 2 uses `ampa_pl011` and I don't want use DMA. Can you tell me how to do that on this driver?

I tried to comment this line in `pl011_startup()` function but seem that it not effect.

```
/* Startup DMA */
//pl011_dma_startup(uap);
```

Have anything more that we need to change?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *latency issue*?

Comment: @goldilocks he may be experiencing an "overpoll" condition due to desktop-like preemption on low-HZ kernel timer

Comment: Hi goldilocks, latency is delay time between 2 byte sent, it's too long when run with my application base on uart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue. Because my application just send 1 byte at time but FIFO in uart driver setting with 8 byte FIFO trigger. That's root cause, we just need reduce down to 1 byte FIFO trigger. Thanks everyone, Thanks Alex so much for your support.!

Answer (score 1):

If the **device chip/implementation** requires DMA - you can not disable it, because there will be no way to transfer data there and back again. And - about the latency - usind DMA reduces latency, definitely not increasing it! You should try a different timer HZ frequencies for your kernel config to play with latencies, but never disable a DMA! Also try to change the preemption/task-switching algorythm in your kernel config. It seems that your kernel does not fit your task.

UPDATE: here is the video https://youtu.be/b-wYeuuxZnc

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Because I have same issue on freescale imx6 about latency , after that I resolved it by disable DMA in imx uart driver. How do you think if I do that on rpi2 ? 
1. used DMA in imx_startup function :
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/tty/serial/imx.c?id=abc7882aacdb4b0e110026bff9b52fb783f4ebd8
2. remove DMA in imx_startup function, I resolved by do like that :
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/tty/serial/imx.c?id=0c727a42043f79db210cdde0366f9137b9c6bf5a

Comment: The source way seems reasonable too, but I'd recommend to try a different hz/taskswitching algo first. I'm currently having no trouble with rpi2 uart at all : pi@pi ~ $ uname -a
Linux pi.local 4.1.15-rpi #1 Wed Jan 13 00:48:00 UTC 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux

Comment: Thanks . But not easy to upgrade to new kernel because my application base on UART is wrote with kernel 3.18. On this kernel version, will not happen if I use sample application on uart, just happen latency with my application. The same on imx6.

Comment: About different hz/taskswitching. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: `make menuconfig` and try to switch options in timer frequency and Preemption Type. Kernel 3.18 is way too old, try a mainline one?

Comment: Hi Alexey Vesnin. where I can change hz/taskswitching? I can't found it in menuconfig?

Comment: @dongpham HZ is a timer frequency in CPU/General settings, preemption model should be around there. Do you need a video to point you to the exact options?

Comment: @dongpham My facebook is [here](https://facebook.com/avesnin) and in my profile, video is on it's way

Comment: Hi Alexey ! This is [config.gz](https://cdn.fbsbx.com/hphotos-xpf1/v/t59.2708-21/12835369_939069649541496_1249725580_n.gz/config.gz?oh=aa49e877a4278d0f81e081a171f8bcd7&oe=57093AAC&dl=1) file that I got from /proc/config.gz on rpi board.

Comment: @dongpham OMG! You have 100HZ(!!!) kernel - of course it's laggy like hell [ CONFIG_HZ=100 in your config ]. Even a RT(RealTime) kernel won't give you a good speed!

Comment: Can you tell me what number we should to change for CONFIG_HZ? I will try again. But I can see this number is default when build kernel on imx6 and rpi. Thanks !

Comment: @dongpham I've pointed a video for you. If you will need further info - say it =)

Comment: As your video, I have tried it but still have latency over than 3ms. You can see wave form in this [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fwzRv.png)

Comment: have you re-compiled and installed a new kernel? Which HZ you've used? can you post your new config.gz ?

Comment: I rebuild and already boot with new kernel, I used 1000HZ, no force preemption.

Comment: post your new config.gz please - I'll try to edit it manually, or let's use a TeamViewer and I'll connect to you?

Comment: This is new config file, [link](https://cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.2708-21/12502751_939307652851029_312387856_n.zip/config_rpi_new.zip?oh=5d139709f40f2bcf59725c303e153f95&oe=570A3B25&dl=1) . I will prepare at home for Teamviewer in tomorrow. Thanks so much Alex.

Comment: by the way - why so old kernel? try 4.1 or 4.4 ?

Comment: And have you recompiled your software with a new kernel?

Comment: Hi Alex. Today, I already update kernel and my uart driver, application to 4.1 and config kernel same you but it still latency. you can see my config kernel 4.1 in this [link](https://cdn.fbsbx.com/hphotos-xaf1/v/t59.2708-21/12384560_941097572672037_2098643997_n.1_config/pi2_4.1_config?oh=deaed0f4bc1342e977dc06a514befa00&oe=570E1036&dl=1)

Comment: @dongpham try to disable a *tickless* option - will it be better? if not - we will hack some kernel source then ;) Don't worry - we will crack it!